# New Network Dataset Error: "There are no feature classes in the network container that can be added as feature sources"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, network, feature-class

I have three feature classes in a database: a line feature class with roads, a point feature class with road intersections, and another point feature class that I would like to use as starting points for a service area calculation using Network Analyst in ArcMap 10.3.

When I try to create a new Network Dataset, I get an error that reads:

> There are no feature classes in the network container that can be added as feature sources.

What exactly is a feature source, and how can I create a network data set using these shape files?

What qualities must a feature class possess in order to be added as a feature source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature Classes must first be added to the Network Dataset. Having them in the same geodatabase is not enough.